# Migrating AD info from 2008 R2 to 2019 - is the process different for VMs?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, migration, windows-server-2019

I was looking for information on how to migrate domain info from a Windows 2008 R2 server VM to a new 2019 server VM. I found info that essentially says to install a new 2019 server on the domain, promote it to domain controller, transfer all AD roles, then un-promote and decommission the old server (nothing specifically about VMs). This may be a dumb question but I'm learning - is there any way this process would be different on a VM? I believe it is hyper v. Or does the same thing apply? My assumption is it works the same way but in case I'm missing something I appreciate if anyone can shed some light on that.

Thank you,

-learning noob

Comment: You must migrate from FRS to DFSR prior to promoting a Windows Server 2019 Domain Controller, so make sure you've done that before attempting to promote the new DC.

Comment: Mentioning that just in case: Reverting to an earlier snapshots as a fail sage mechanism for borked migrations is most likely going to make it worse.

Comment: @joeqwerty yes that I've also seen but thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @Daniel could you elaborate on that - why would it make it worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is correct, there is no difference at all in the process if the involved server are physical or virtual.